# Error in connecting Superset with Hive Kerberos

Tags: hive, kerberos, apache-superset

As I'm trying to connect superset to hive kerberos, which uses sqlalchemy uri to connect. The uri im using to connect is: hive2://hkiva***.nk.******.com.:10000/adssit_cic-usr_vr;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=ZONE1.**DEV.NET

[Test Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z31G.jpg)

For which im getting the folllowing error in the backend:

10.**4.*.0 -

- (03/0et/2023:06:52:29 +0000] "POST /ap1/vi/database/ #TTP/1.1" 422 71 "hetp://10.7.8.*:31430/aug

NebRat/537.36 (KHTML, 11ke Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safar1/537.36*

CommandException

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/app/superset/databases/commands/test_connection.py", line 81, in zun

engine = database.get_ sqla_engine ()

File "/app/superset/utils/memolzed.py", line 50, in

cal1

value = self. func (*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/superset/models/core›py", line 413, in get_ sqla_engine raise self.db_engine_spec.get_ dbapi_mapped_exception (ex) file "/app/superset/modeis/core.py", line 411, in get sqLa_engine return create engine (sqlalchemy _url, **params)

File "/ast/local/11b/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/_init

•py", line 525, in create_ engine

return strategy.create (*args,

**kwargs)

File "/usr/local/11b/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 61, in create

entrypoint = u. get entrypoint ()

File w/usI/local/Ilb/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py",line172,in_get_entrypoint

cls = registry. load (name)

File "/us/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ut11/langhelpers.py",line277,in load raise exc. NoSuchModuleError (

sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:hive

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app-py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request

TV self.dispatch request ()

File "/usr/local/11b/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app-py", line 1502, in dispatch_request return self.ensure_sync (self.view_functions [rule.endpoint]) (**req.view_args)

Bile */ast/local/11b/python3.B/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/decorators-py", Line 82, in wraps return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/ superset/views/base api.py", line 113, in wraps

raise ex

File "/app/superset/views/base _api,py", line 110, in wraps duration, response - time_function (f, self, *args,

**kwargs)

File "/app/superset/ut11s/core.py", line 1524, in time_function

I

response - func (*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/superset/utils/log.py", line 245, in wrapper

value = £ (*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/superset/views/base_api,py", line 83, in wraps

return 1 (self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/superset/databases/api,py", line 712, in test_connection

TestConnectionDatabaseCommand (g user, item) , run ()

File "/app/superset/databases/commands/test_connection,py", line 133, in run

raise DatabaseTestConnectionDriverErIOr\

superset .databases, commands, exceptions, DatabaseTestConnectionDriverError: Could not load database driver: BaseEngineSpec

2023-10-03 06:54:14,413;WARNING: superset, views. base: CommandException Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/app/superset/databases/commands/test connection.py", line 81, in run

I tried to connect Superset to Hive Kerberos and was expecting it to create a successful connection. As given in documentation I have installed PyHive. Currently what I'm unsure of is how to pass Kerberos keytabs or credentials through Superset ui.